# Apple distribution certificate upload

Tags: ios, safari, appstore-approval

I've created a private and public key using keychain as explained in the development portal. However, whenever trying to upload the certificate to get a distribution certificate in the portal at https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/createDistribute.action and pressing "submit" the Safari browser crashes. I tried to upload it also in Chrome, but it never gets to the next pages, and always reloads the submit page. I'm confused... please advise...

PS: I had the same problem submitting a developer certificate. I managed to work around it by using XCode's Organizer tool this is great, but unfortunately it doesn't work for submitting a distribution certificate.

Comment: Are you sure you are following the instructions correctly? Sounds like you aren't You don't  need to submit a certificate to Apple, but a certificate request… it's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a browser issue.  I've been working heavily in the provisioning area of the Developer Portal and haven't had any issues.

- Try a different browser like [Firefox](http://www.getfirefox.net/)

Other than that make sure that you're uploading the correct file.  The certificate for approval that you upload on the Certificates > Development area should have a .certSigningRequest extension.

Any other files that you add to DEVICES as a provisioning profile should have a .mobileprovision file extension.

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same problem. When I switched browser it worked. (It didn't work with Chrome. It did work with Safari)